# how to truncate or reset mysql 5.7 statement_analysis table in sys schema

Tags: mysql

I am using statement_analysis table to check which sql execute topest times, now I optimize the sql query in my app but some old query times data in statement_analysis table, how to reset statement_analysis data and reperformance the database ? I am tried this but all failed:

```
delete from sys.statement_analysis where exec_count > 4000000;
truncate table sys.statement_analysis;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this:

```
CALL sys.ps_truncate_all_tables(TRUE);
```

works.